# how to disable/remove/override css property of a CDN

Tags: html, css, swiper.js

i am using swiper.js via CDN...the problem is that in swiper-bundle.min.css CDN file `.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev` are set to `top:50%;`  like this:-

```css
.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

I want to set `.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev` to `bottom:11px;` i tried doing it in my own css file but CDN's `top:50%` is overriding it. And i've tried using `!important` too but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the same class in your project's main `css` file and do the styling with `!important` keyword.

```
.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: unset !important;
    bottom: 11px;
}
```

[Here is fiddle with a simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/nLjd5pqf/). In this Fiddle, I have included [**bootstrap CDN**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/) and overridden the padding of `.container` class to demonstrate